# React Map function not rendering on browser, but it is console.logging

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, rest, react-hooks

I'm working on a React homework assignment, working with the pokemon API. In this particular component, I'm accessing the API to return a list of all the pokemon names and render them to the browser.

I've called the API and mapped it out, and it seems to work when I console.log the names, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong that it is not rendering onto the actual browser, and could definitely use some help. Code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function PokedexHome(){
    const [pokedexList, setPokedexList] = useState(undefined);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [hasError, setHasError] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=100&offset=0`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
                setPokedexList(data)
                setIsLoading(false);
            },
            error => {
                setHasError(true)
                setIsLoading(false)
            }
        );
    },[]);

    if(isLoading){
        return <p>Loading...</p>
    }

    if(hasError){
        return <p>An error has occurred, please try again later</p>
    }
    
    pokedexList.results.map((pokemon) => {
        console.log(pokemon.name)
        return <div className="list-container">
             <p>{pokemon.name}</p>
            </div>
           
      })
    };
      


export default PokedexHome
```

Answer (score 2):

if you have a list then your `PokedexHome` returns `void` :)

so, first of all, you are missing a `return` before the map.

second, (if nothing changed lately) you can't return an array of components, you need to return a single component, which can be a `Fragment` (a React component without UI representation, created for this purpose)

```
return (
  <>
    {
      pokedexList.results.map((pokemon) => {
        console.log(pokemon.name)
        return <div className="list-container">
             <p>{pokemon.name}</p>
            </div>
           
      })

    }
  </>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You miss the return keyword in front if pokedexList. It should be like this. And also add `()` on your return

```
return pokedexList.results.map((pokemon) => {
    return (
      <div className="list-container">
        <p>{pokemon.name}</p>
      </div>
    )
       
  })
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your component need to return a `JSX`, so add return and wrap your list with `<></>`.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function PokedexHome() {
  const [pokedexList, setPokedexList] = useState(undefined);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [hasError, setHasError] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=100&offset=0`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(
        (data) => {
          setPokedexList(data);
          setIsLoading(false);
        },
        (error) => {
          setHasError(true);
          setIsLoading(false);
        },
      );
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }

  if (hasError) {
    return <p>An error has occurred, please try again later</p>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      {pokedexList.results.map((pokemon) => {
        console.log(pokemon.name);
        return (
          <div className="list-container">
            <p>{pokemon.name}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most probable issue I can think of here is, you are not wrapping the whole JSX in () round braces. It specifies that you want to return something. With main function return statement of course

Example code

> Try wrapping it like this.

```
return  pokedexList.results.map((pokemon) => (
        
         <div className="list-container">
             <p>{pokemon.name}</p>
            </div>
           
      ))
```

Comment: if you are talking about the map's return statement, it won't because <div> is the only parent element in the map which is wrapping <p>.

Comment: If there's one div as a parent element then it doesn't matter, please refer to this fiddle link :
[link]:https://jsfiddle.net/JNishant29/wnk8tu62/7/